# Bootstrap-Select not updating on mobile

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using [Bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/) for multi-select items with Django. It works fine on desktop, but when the native mobile drop-down is enabled, the selected values of the dropdown do not populate.

```
HTML
<!-- start product brand info -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-*">
            <div>
                <label for="id_brand-name" class="form-label">Products</label>
            </div>
            <select multiple class="form-control selectpicker mb-3" id="id_brand-name" name="brand-name" mobile="true" multiple required>
                {% for product in products %}
                <option value="{{product.id}}" id="optiion">{{ product.brand.name | title }} - {{product.name | title}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Select at least one product.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end product info -->

<script>
    //Enble native drop down on mobile
    window.onload = function () {
    $('#id_brand-name').selectpicker({
        container: 'body'   
    });

    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        $('#id_brand-name').selectpicker('mobile')
    }};
</script>
```

No matter how many items are selected, the selector always shows `Nothing selected`. When the data is posted, it is apart of the form though.

[image: Ex on Mobile]

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/), but this problem has been bothering me for a long time
Similar questions can be found on github, but no perfect answer.

The reason is that it will always refresh his `title`, no matter how `remove()` is done externally, and you **can't change it's style on iphone Safari and Firefox**.

So my solution is: if you can't remove it, then join it.

You have to change the original file: **bootstrap-select.js**

Search for: `bs-title-option`, next line you will find:

```js
this.selectpicker.view.titleOption.value = '';
```

And add two lines down:

```js
this.selectpicker.view.titleOption.value = '';
// new add
this.selectpicker.view.titleOption.disabled='true';
this.selectpicker.view.titleOption.textContent=this.options.title;
//
```

**Done**

When you use `$('#id_brand-name').selectpicker('mobile')`

The `title` text show on first empty option, and it can't be choose.

try it!

Comment: This is for v1.13.17 and v1.13.18. Using `title` to set the select's placeholder will be deprecated for v1.14.0.
https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/releases